# Probability / Mean of randomly drawn sequence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let's say I have a real valued random variable $X$ distributed according to a continuous *non normal* cdf $G(x)$ with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. Furthermore I have a set of natural number $[k]$ where $\{k \in \mathbb{N} : 0 < k < 30\}$. Now I go on as follows:

1. From $[k]$ I randomly sample one number $K$
2. I sample a random sequence of size $K$ $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_K\}$ from $X$.

What is now the probability that the sample mean $\frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^K x_k$ is smaller than a constant $Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\ K\ $, the conditional distribution , $\ \mathbb P\left(\sum_\limits{j=1}^K x_j\le y\left\vert K \right.\right) \ $, of $\ \sum_\limits{j=1}^K x_j\ $ is the $K$-fold convolution $\ G^{*K}(y)\ $, where $\ G*F(y)=\int_\limits{-\infty}^\infty G(y-t)dF(t)\ $, and $\ G^{*k} = \underset{k \text{ factors}}{\underbrace{G*G*\dots*G}}\ $.  Thus, the distribution, $\ \mathbb P\left(\frac{1}{K}\sum_\limits{j=1}^K x_j\le y\right)\ $, of $\ \frac{1}{K}\sum_\limits{j=1}^K x_j\ $ is given by
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb P\left(\frac{1}{K}\sum_\limits{j=1}^K x_j\le y\right)&=& \sum_\limits{k=1}^{29}\mathbb P\left(\frac{1}{K}\sum_\limits{j=1}^K x_j\le y\left\vert K=k \right.\right) \mathbb P(K=k)\\
&=& \frac{1}{29}\sum_\limits{k=1}^{29}G^{*k}(ky)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you very much for your precise answer. After I have now understood what you wrote, I understood that my question was not sophisticated enough to solve my problem at hand. I reposted a somewhat similar but more elaborated question. In case u have some capacity left, your comments are again very welcomed... here is the link:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362173/probability-two-random-variables-mean-of-two-randomly-drawn-sequences